# How can i choose just one object?

Tags: c++, object, scope

Hi I have created two dictionaries with a different implementation (Red Black Trees and Hash Table)
I have to create just one object of my dictionary named istanza_vocabolario.

Inside `main` I use for example `istanza_vocabolario->Cancella(parola_new)`
According to my choose, `istanza_vocabolario` has to be `VocabolarioRB*` type or `Vocabolario*` .

I can't create a function because I can't know if I have to return a `Vocabolario` pointer or `VocabolarioRB` pointer. If I declare the object into the IF, then occurs scope errors.
How can I do?
Sorry for bad English, thank you!

```
#include "abstract_Vocabolario.h"
#include "abstract_Vocabolario.cpp"

#include "VocabolarioRB.h"
#include "Vocabolario.h"
#include "Vocabolario.cpp"

using namespace std;

char Menu();

int main()
{


         VocabolarioRB* istanza_vocabolario = new VocabolarioRB;

        int scelta_vocabolario;
        cout<<"Quale vocabolario vuoi utilizzare (1 per RedBlack o 2 per HashTable) ?"<<endl;
        cin>>scelta_vocabolario;


        if (scelta_vocabolario == 2 )
        {
            delete istanza_vocabolario;
            Vocabolario* istanza_vocabolario = new Vocabolario;
        }


        while(true)
        {
            char scelta=Menu();
            switch(scelta)
            {
            case '1':
                    {
                    cout<<" 1)Inserimento parola"<<endl;
                    string parola_new;
                    cout<<endl<<" Inserisci parola da immettere nel vocabolario:\n ";
                    cin>>parola_new;
                    if (istanza_vocabolario->Inserisci(parola_new) != 0 )
                        cout << "Inserito con successo" << endl;
                    else
                        cout << "Inserimento non avvenuto" << endl;
                    }
                    break;
            case '2':
                {
                cout<<" 3)Ricerca parola"<<endl;
                string parola_ricercata;
                cout<<endl<<" Inserisci parola da RICERCARE nel vocabolario:\n ";
                cin>>parola_ricercata;
                istanza_vocabolario->Ricerca(parola_ricercata);
                }
                break;

            //case '3':
                //istanza_vocabolario->Visita_Albero();       //MOMENTANEAMENTE VALE SOLO PER IL DIZIONARIO 2
                //break;

            case '4':

                {
                cout<<" 4)Eliminazione parola"<<endl;
                string parola_new;
                cout<<endl<<" Inserisci parola da eliminare nel vocabolario: ";
                cin>>parola_new;
                if (istanza_vocabolario->Cancella(parola_new) != 0)
                    cout<< "Eliminato con successo" << endl;
                else
                cout <<"Eliminazione NON avvenuta" << endl;
                }


                break;

            case 'E':
                delete istanza_vocabolario;
                return 0;

            default:
                cout<<" ATTENZIONE";
                cout<<" valore inserito non valido."<<endl;
            }
        }


return 0;
}

char Menu()
{
    cout<<endl<<endl<<" Menu Vocabolario"<<endl<<endl;;
    cout<<" Scegli l'operazione da compiere:"<<endl<<endl;
    cout<<" 1";
    cout<<" - Inserisci nuova parola;"<<endl;
    cout<<" 2";
    cout<<" - Ricerca parola;"<<endl;
    cout<<" 3";
    cout<<" - Visualizza albero;"<<endl;
    cout<<" 4";
    cout<<" - Elimina parola;"<<endl;
    cout<<" E";
    cout<<" - Esci dal programma."<<endl<<" ";;
    cout<<endl<<" Digita il numero dell'operazione: ";
    char valore;
    cin>>valore;
    cout<<endl;
    return valore;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what *interfaces* are for!

Do this:

- Declare an abstract class called `Vocabulario`
- Make `VocabolarioRB` inherit from `Vocabulario`
- Make `VocabolarioHT` inherit from `Vocabulario`
  <sup>(this is what you're calling `Vocabulario` at the moment)</sup>

Each of these types should have the same member functions. Then, in your `main`, it doesn't really matter which implementation you've chosen, because you just call the functions you need through a `Vocabulario*` pointer.

```
const bool use_hash = false;
std::unique_ptr<Vocabulario> ptr(
   use_hash
   ? new VocabularioRB()
   : new VocabularioHT()
);

ptr->foo();
ptr->bar();
```

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I don't know what you're talking about! Ahem.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Gah! Shush! This new-fangled monstrosiceeplusplus!

Answer (score 0):

thank you for replace!
I used Abstract_dictionary as abstract class and then VocabolarioRB inherit from abstract_dictionary and also VocabolarioHT inherit from abstract_dictionary.
Into the main i used "istanza_vocabolario" that can be related to VocabolarioRB if users chooses 1 or VocabolarioHT if user chooses 2.
In the abrasct class i have just variables and methods both common. There are virtual methods that I overrid with specifical class.
I don't understand your function. I am working on c++
I have to return VocabolarioRB pointer OR VocabolarioHT pointer. So i can write:
VocabolarioRB * istanza_vocabolario= new VocabolarioRB;
or
VocabolarioHT * istanza_vocabolario= new VocabolarioHT;

and use in my main istanza_vocabolario->Insert/Delete/Find

Thank you!

Comment: Actually, I am using "new" so why if I declare an object into the IF then occurs scope errors? I am using dynamic allocation :s